# MassTransit is it possible to consume a message from a queue only on-demand?

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, microservices, masstransit

How can I, or is it even possible to, consume messages from a queue on-demand. That is, for messages to remain in the queue and not to be automatically deliverd to their consumers?

Based on all that I have read in the MassTransit documentation and by design it seems that such behaviour is not possible without using 'hacks'. Unless I drop MassTransit and switch purely to RabbitMQ, which I need to look deeper into to find out if such scenario is possible.

I would really appreciate any insights, tips or guidance into the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MassTransit does not support on-demand, or pull-based, messaging. Transports push messages from the broker (except SQS, because, well, it's SQS) but don't expose any way for developers to "get just one" or other types of polling.

Comment: What is the best way to thread them one by one, one after the other ?